# Displaying all the data without using databound controllers ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table named "Rezervare" with the field `id`, `id_hotel`, `data_inceput`, `data_sfarsit`, `pret`.
My task is to display all the records without using databound controllers . Afterwards I need to update and delete them so I need to select specific id's to do those operations.

Since I am new to C# and ASP I don't know how to display and make buttons that would take the right id on press in order to delete or update a record in the table.

To sum things up I have 2 questions:

1. How do I display the data in the table without using listview,detailsview,formview etc.?
2. How do I make buttons for each of the item that on press take the right id(just like in listview would)? 
   (I don't know the answer to the 1st question so that answer might just answer my 2nd)

Comment: Why would you do that? Re-invent what already exists? Please tell us why you have to do this

Comment: well the final at this subject will be on PC . the things that we will have to do are very simple (we received a model for the test upcoming). And in that model(which will be respected) we have to update, delete and show the reservations(rezervare = reservation) without using databound controllers . Don't ask me why , I gave up a long time ago to find the logic in what teachers ask(I had to redo a part of my project with SqlConn and SqlCommand just to show that I know them since I used Linq for the project... )

Comment: If you want to _learn_ then at the core of this web stuff is HTTP Request and Response. You can then output whatever you want by going "bare metal" - and that's probably why your teacher made you understand/learn/familiarize `SqlConn`, `SqlCommand`, etc. which should now hopefully "make logical sense" of what/why teachers ask what they ask. Hth.

Comment: You are very right but i was hoping there was a foreach statement like in ruby that i could use... otherwise making each of the reservation elements selectable to be edited is kind of hard for me at least :))

Comment: Using asp.net mvc would be better for this but if this is not an option, you have more work to do. You have to mind the ViewState and Page Life Cycle if you want a table that can do edit/insert/delete, something I would never do. A simpler way I would go is make the table readonly, then have a separate page for insert, edit and delete. You can use `<asp:Table />` to achieve this, building each row and each cells, then add links to the edit and delete page using the id of each record